# Escaping apostrophies and other characters in text area

Tags: php, html, forms, escaping, textarea

So I have found that this form I have just falls apart and doesn't even submit the content up until the first apostrophe when someone types in an apostrophe to this text area. How do I go about escaping the contents so they make it into my MySQL table? Thanks!

```
<form action=\"./functions/notes.php\" method='post'>
<input type='hidden' id='ID' name='ID' value='{$row['ID']}' />

<textarea placeholder=\"Add more notes here...\" name=\"notes\"></textarea><br />
<input type='submit' name='formNotes' id='formNotes' value='Add to Notes' />
</form>
```

then in the notes.php file

```
$notesID = $_POST['ID'];
$note = $_POST['notes'];
$date= date('Y-m-d');
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE Project_Submissions SET Notes=CONCAT(Notes,'<br />".$date." ".$note."') WHERE ID ='".$notesID."'");
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html). If you use prepared statements you do not have to worry about escaping *anything*.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Im using mysqli instead of mysql. Do you think there are problems with that? I dont know of functions comparable to  mysqli_fetch_assoc for returning everything I need. And I read that mysqli is improved version.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez actually, urlencode is the wrong function/method here. The correct answer would be to bind your queries, the ok/bad answer would be to escape your queries. Using urlencode would require you to urldecode when pulling the value out or else you would end up with a bunch of `%20` values (and other url entities) in your text. At the VERY least, pass it into htmlentities.

Comment: @Zapp mysqli is fine compared to PDO. Choosing which is just personal preference. The key is to BIND your queries instead of building a query using concatenation and escaping. Oh, and yes, mysqli is improved mysql. Mysql will be removed in future version.

Comment: `mysqli_*` functions are fine @Zapp, I just prefer (as do many, many others) `PDO`.

Comment: I truly understand your points, my learning process is going to be to write the code as I know how to write it and then update the code. It's too hard for me to be debugging code with syntax I'm not as familiar with. I want to settle in with the code I know and get it right and then I can learn how to fix it. Just like refactoring an old system, on step at a time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apostrophes have special meaning to SQL, so to get them into the data they need to be "escaped"  PHP has a quick function for this that also does some security checks to help prevent your database from getting hacked.

```
$note = mysql_real_escape_string($note);
```

DITTO on moving away from mysql and onto mysqlI

with MySQLI, it's similar you just need to supply the connection variable....

```
$note = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $note);
```

Comment: thank you! this was helpful and showed me how to make the changes